# How to remove immediate slash(/) after hash(#) in angular

Tags: angular

I configured my angular 8 app routing with **{useHash:true}**.

When i opened a url in browser say for example

```
https://localhost:4200/#/todo
https://localhost:4200/#/todo/12
```

I do not want that additional / immediately after #. what configuration has to be added in angular to achieve above.

```
https://localhost:4200/#todo
https://localhost:4200/#todo/12
```

I have this requirement so that my urls are compatible with routes of my non angular microservices which are been loaded inside angular apps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{useHash:true}` exists firstly for old browsers, that do not support [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Without # it wasn't possible to change url without reloading the whole page. I would recommend you not to use hash in your app. The behavior you are trying to change is not configurable.