# Javascript - Forward Slash appended automatically in URL with the Window.Location.Hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window.location

In my Angular JS website, I wish to append the text "#Page/" to the URL using Javascript. Here my problem is that the forward slash(/) is getting added when using the code Location.hash

For example, Let say the URL is `https://MyWebsite.com/Products`

```
        var location = window.location;
        location.hash = "#page/" + pageNumber;
        window.location = location
```

After executing the above code, the Window.location turned out to be `https://MyWebsite.com/Products/#page/1`.

But what I need is the forward slash(/) should not be included between products and #page.
`https://MyWebsite.com/Products#page/1`.

The strange thing is that when I checked the same code with the other websites don't have Angular JS, implemented only with the Asp.net Webforms and ASP.net MVC, I got the desired result.

Does this kind of issue have something to do with the Angular JS?

Comment: One question, does the added slash compromise your link OR does it work just the same?

Comment: @GrafiCode ..Thanks for your message. Actually, there is a function that loads the image file based on the URL #page<Number>. Due to the added Slash, the function is not working.

Comment: I think this is very related, unfortunately it doesn't provide a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60396445/how-to-remove-immediate-slash-after-hash-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

I believe # is special character reserved for a page fragment reference.
See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Can you do with without # or use the # to reference the fragment? e.g.

```
window.location.href += 'page/' + pageNumber + '#' + pageFragment;
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. Yes I tried it but the issue haven't resolved.  Even when I use the static link "window.location.href="http://localhost:56008/FlipBook/Flip#page/1", it still automatically appends the forward slash after hash.. http://localhost:56008/FlipBook/Flip#/page/1